# Is being mutually exclusive and independent is the same thing?

Tags: probability

If i say 2 events are mutually exclusive ,is it the same thing saying that they two are independent of each other?

Comment: ok..I know it's a stupid Qus :-)

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/a/23485/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider exclusive event $A$ and $\bar A$.

Comment: ok..so A and /barA ,they are exclusive i.e. the sample spaces have nothig in common. but saying are they 2 independent,are they? I think they could be  or could be not.

Comment: Do you know the **definition** of independent?

Comment: What is the definition of independent?

Comment: They occurrence of one doesn't have any effect on of another.

Comment: Ok i figured it Out ,please correct me If I am wrong. If they don't have anything in common(Sample spaces) only then we need to bother about whether they are independent or not(to calculate a(intersection)b),if they don't have anything in common,we shouldn't.

Comment: @user2509211 I don't understand your last comment.  Can you translate your definition of independence into a precise statement about probabilities?

Comment: @TrevorWilson Two events A and B are called independent if probability of  occurrence of either event doesn't have any effect on the probability of occurrence of another event. (Kinda Vague,but that's what I think)

Comment: @user2509211: Can you look up the definition of independence as a  precise statement about probabilities?

Comment: @JonasMeyer  "occurrence of one does not affect the probability of the other".

Comment: @user2509211 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#Two_events.

Comment: I almost got the ans. Should this Qus be deleted?

Comment: @user2509211 No, you should leave it in case others come to the site later with a similar question.  If you want, you can edit it to add any further question you might have about the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative hint:  Toss a penny and a nickel in the air and consider the independent events (1) the penny comes up heads and (2) the nickel comes up heads.

Comment: i think these 2 events are independent ,but are they mutually exclusive? I think No,they ain't.

Comment: @user2509211 That's right, they are independent but it is possible (with probability $1/4$) for both to happen.

Comment: p(a and b)=p(a)p(b)..yes. but is it application of formula that we deduce whether 2 events are independent or first we decided that they are independent and then apply formula?

Comment: @user2509211 Both. In case you can safely assume that $A$ and $B$ are independent then you can calculate $P(A\cap B)$.  Otherwise if you know $P(A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(A\cap B)$  you can determine wether $A$ and $B$ are independent or not.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Then it's easily shown that $A$ and $B$ are independent iff $P(A)\cdot P(B)=0$.